# How to move the SharePoint Search Service Application database?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search, database

Can anybody suggest me how to move  Search Service Application database and components to other server under the same farm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 Search: Moving the Query Component to a Web Front End

Reference link - http://stevemannspath.blogspot.in/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-search-moving-query.html

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Clone the active search topology
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$active = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Active
$clone = New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Clone –SearchTopology $active

# Add New Search Component
$wfe = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity "<<web front end server name here>>"
New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryProcessingComponent -SearchTopology $clone -SearchServiceInstance $wfe

# Start Instance On Different Server
Start-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Identity $wfe

# Activate  Search Topology
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $clone

# Clone Again 
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$active = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Active
$clone = New-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -SearchApplication $ssa -Clone –SearchTopology $active

# Get the Search Component ID To Move
$queryComponentID = (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -SearchTopology $clone -Identity QueryProcessingComponent1).componentID

# Remove Search Component
Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchComponent -Identity $queryComponentID.GUID  -SearchTopology $clone -confirm:$false

# Activate  Search Topology Again
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -Identity $clone
```

Answer (score 0):

To move the Search Components of SharePoint 2013 to another server you can use PowerShell.

[Link](https://altfo.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/move-search-components-to-different-server-in-sharepoint-2013/)